# Enumerator and disposing in F#

Tags: f#, ienumerable, idisposable

I am trying to draw lessons on the following behaviour from an example I simplified  :

```
let groupedEnum  (input: 'a seq) =
   using (input.GetEnumerator()) (fun en ->
   Seq.unfold(fun _ -> 
                  if en.MoveNext() then 
                     Some(en.Current, ())
                  else None) ()
   )


//WORKS    
let c = groupedEnum    ("11111122334569999"   |>  List.ofSeq ) |>  List.ofSeq 

//BOOM !!  System.NullReferenceException
let c = groupedEnum    ("11111122334569999"                  ) |>  List.ofSeq
```

- Is the enumerator "en" disposed of independently of it being captured ? (I guess it is but is there anything to say / materials to read on this behaviour beside [this msdn doc on ressources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240.aspx))
- Why is it working if the sequence is transformed to a list first ?

**Edit :** this is just a toy example to illustrate a behaviour, not to be followed.
There are very few good reasons to manipulate enumerators directly.

Comment: What does "boom" mean? What symptoms are you seeing? Leaving people to guess does not invite good input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `using` function disposes the enumerator as soon as the lambda function returns. However, the lambda function creates a lazy sequence using `Seq.unfold` and the lazy sequence accesses the enumerator *after* the sequence is returned from `groupedEnum`.

You could either fully evaluate the whole sequence inside `using` (by adding `List.ofSeq` there) or you need to call `Dispose` when the end of the generated sequence is reached:

```
let groupedEnum  (input: 'a seq) =
   let en = input.GetEnumerator()
   Seq.unfold(fun _ -> 
       if en.MoveNext() then 
           Some(en.Current, ())
       else 
           en.Dispose()
           None)
```

Exception handling becomes quite difficult in this case, but I guess that one way to do it would be to wrap the body in `try .. with` and call `Dispose` if an exception happens (and then return `None`).

If you use sequence expressions instead, then the meaning of `use` changes and it automatically disposes the enumerator after the end of sequence is reached (not when the lazy sequence is returned). So using sequence expressions might be a better choice because the hard work is done for you:

```
let groupedEnum  (input: 'a seq) = seq {
   use en = input.GetEnumerator()
   let rec loop () = seq {
      if en.MoveNext() then 
         yield en.Current
         yield! loop () }
   yield! loop () }
```

**EDIT** And why does it work in your first example? The enumerator returned by F# list type simply ignores `Dispose` and continues working, while if you call `Dispose` on an enumerator returned by a `string`, the enumerator cannot be used again. (This is arguably a bit odd behaviour of the F# list type.)

Comment: How nice and easy this "seq {}" expression is. Going to enumerator level is in most case unnecessary and a code smell, just playing around with it. indeed the list enumerator is not doing anything https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs

Comment: I'm not sure if it was omitted for a reason, but to get the first code block to work I needed another `()` after the Seq.unfold